# Angular aperture of diverging beam after passing through a diverging lens

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometric-optics, lenses

Consider an optical set-up as shown in the plot below: A light source, e.g. a laser diode, of diameter $d$ ($\approx$ 1 mm, but numbers are unimportant) is emitting a divergent beam having a half opening angle of $\alpha$. A diverging lens (focal length $f$) is in a distance of $y$.

The question is, what is the angle $\alpha'$ after the beam has passed the diverging lens? (For parallel incoming light this is trivial and covered in every physics book, but what if the incoming ray is already divergent?)

[image]

Note, in the plot the distance to the lens is larger than the focal length ($y > f$), but that can be vice versa (or even $y = f$), I'm looking for a general equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sketch let (x) be the horizontal side opposite the angle α, giving x/y = tan(α) where y is the object distance with 1/y + 1/y' = 1/f (f and y' are negative).  The (y') is the virtual image distance, and x/y' = tan(α').   Then 1/y' = tan(α')/[y tan( α)].  Finally  1/y +  tan(α')/[y tan(α)] = 1/f.  (I'll let you deal with the negative numbers.)

Comment: Many thanks! So the point is that from the outside (top in the sketch) the light source appears to be closer beneath the lens, and the emitted light is therefore seen to be emitted under a larger angle. Is that correct?

Comment: The light leaving the lens appears to be coming from the virtual image which is between the object and the lens.

Comment: But the virtual image is not only closer to the lens but has also another size than the object - that would affect the angle as well, in principle. I guess that is neglected in your solution as the effect is small (because the object is usually small)?

Comment: I have considered a beam from only one point on the object. The angular size of the image is a different question.

Comment: Thanks, I got it!